# Why the customize contextmenu not working when i click using flex builder 4.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, mxml, flash

Hi i have creating a video player using flex builder 4.5 and it's almost done in my local it's working fine but when i publish my swf file into the server i got this problem when i try to right click and select one of the contextmenu item it did not work. Do you know what is the problem with this?

> Here is my codes:

```
            import flash.events.ContextMenuEvent;
            import flash.events.VideoEvent;
            import flash.net.navigateToURL;
            import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
            import flash.ui.ContextMenuBuiltInItems;
            import flash.ui.ContextMenuItem;
            private var report:ContextMenuItem;
            private var tefltv:ContextMenuItem;
            private var developers:ContextMenuItem;
            private var contextMenuCustomItems:Array;
            private var src:String;
            private var param:Array;
            private function init():void {
                contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
                report = new ContextMenuItem("Report Bug", false, true);
                tefltv = new ContextMenuItem("About TEFLTV", false, true);
                developers = new ContextMenuItem("Developers Portal", false, true);
                contextMenuCustomItems = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.contextMenu.customItems;
                contextMenuCustomItems.push(report);
                contextMenuCustomItems.push(tefltv);
                contextMenuCustomItems.push(developers);
                var params:Object = Application(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication).parameters;
                var videoSource:String = params['source'];
                var auto_play:Boolean = params['autoplay'];
                mediaplayer.source = videoSource;
                mediaplayer.autoPlay = auto_play;
                report.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menu);
                tefltv.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menu);
                developers.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, menu);
                p_n_p.source = "assets/pause.jpg";
                mediaplayer.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, videoAddedToStage);
            }   
            private function menu(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
            {
                switch (event.target) {
                    case tefltv:
                        var urlReq_tefltv:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.tefltv.com");
                        navigateToURL(urlReq_tefltv, "_self");
                        break;
                    case report:
                        var urlReq_flex:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.tefltv.com/report-bugs");
                        navigateToURL(urlReq_flex, "_self");
                        break;
                    case developers:
                        var urlReq_developers:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://developers.tefltv.com");
                        navigateToURL(urlReq_developers, "_self");
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Provide more details how you are using the SWF on your server? is it embedded in HTML? Care to share the link?

Comment: this working fine https://www.tefltv.com/tefltv_fl_video_player/tefltv_video_player.swf but when i share my video on facebook using open graph api when i right click the video and click the  contextmenu item it's not working..

Comment: Well, in that case cannot guarantee that it is a Flash problem. Can you share a public URL on facebook and show? I have no idea how facebook works and it may be blocking the URL. Can you also try using "_blank" instead of "_self" in your code and see if it works?

Comment: okay thank you i will try that